# How to make a directory run a htm file

Tags: html, file, redirect, directory

So lets suppose i do have this link:

> test.mywebsite.com/1

Whenever i click on it i will get reinderected into another website using this html code:

```html
<html>

<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=http://mywebsite.com/whatever" /> 
<!-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->

    <link rel="canonical" href="123.jpeg/index.html" />
    <meta content="hahaha WTF so funny " name="description" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="instagram.com" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="hahaha WTF" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="123.jpeg" />
   
<!-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -->
</head>
</html>
```

What i want is that when i click on the link:

> test.mywebsite.com/1

i get redirected on

> mywebsite.com/whatever

and also if i go to:

> test.mywebsite.com/1/123.jpeg

i get to see 123.jpeg photo

Any help please? Thank you!